# Getting specific files from a specific directory in PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking to be able to go through an an entire directory, read all its subfolders and stop at the folder I want. Once I found my sub-folder, I want to be able to open it and display all of its contents. I want to be able to use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` but I don't know how to stop at a directory once its found.

```
public function getFiles($path, $recursive = true) { 

    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path,  RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST)) as $filename)
    {
            echo "$filename\n";
    }   
}
```

This simply displays everything and is pretty much where I'm stuck. My other attempt was the following:

```
public function getFiles($path) { 

    $ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..' ,'...'  ); 
    $dh = @opendir( $path ); 
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) { 
        if(!in_array($file,$ignore )) { 
            if( is_dir( "$path/$file" )) {


                $this->getFiles( "$path/$file"); 

                if($file==$this->job) {
                //if the dir I want is found... open it and display all of it files


                }

            } else {


            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir( $dh ); 
}
```

Though this attempt confused me and I'm not sure what my next option is.

Comment: `if (found) {break;}` the break keyword will end your loop

Comment: From what you are saying, you want to enter a "directory" to be searched for, when it's found, list it's inputs?

Comment: Yea, well I have a bunch of folders somewhere that contain subfolders. I want to be able to search through all the folders and find the one I'm looking for. Once found, reveal its contents.